# Slideshow function doesn't work in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a dynamic code for slideshow. I have looked at it many times, I think everything is right, but it doesn't work. I just cannot find where I have a bug. I hope anyone can show me what is wrong:

```
<button type="button" id="back">&lt;&lt;</button>

<button type="button" id="forward">&gt;&gt;</button>

<img id="photo" src="http://photo.interpressnews.ge/img/image1/b37065d8bf0bd9e25d5bcb3c144b0269.jpg" width="200 height="200>
```

and Javascript:

```
var photos = new Array("http://photo.interpressnews.ge/img/image1/b37065d8bf0bd9e25d5bcb3c144b0269.jpg", "http://photo.interpressnews.ge/img/image1/c81dae9175d056aa243a5a0e56b3c111.jpg", "http://photo.interpressnews.ge/img/image1/5ff96384ddf214ef33706ffdb922b710.jpg");
var imgnumber = 0;
var imgleng = photos.length - 1;
var img = document.getElementById("photo");
var current = photos.indexOf(img.src);
var nextindex;
var back = document.getElementById("back");
var forward = document.getElementById("forward");
back.addEventListener('click', toggleImage('back'));
forward.addEventListener('click', toggleImage('forward'));

function toggleImage(direction) {
   if(direction == 'forward'){
   nextindex = current != photos.length - 1 ? current + 1 : 0;
   } else {

   nextindex = current != 0 ? current - 1 : photos.length - 1;
   }
   img.src = photos[nextindex];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with the onclick event. You are calling the function, instead of binding it to the event listener. The function call with the parameter 'back' or 'forward' must be inside a function. Here is the corrected code:

```
    var photos = new Array("http://photo.interpressnews.ge/img/image1/b37065d8bf0bd9e25d5bcb3c144b0269.jpg", "http://photo.interpressnews.ge/img/image1/c81dae9175d056aa243a5a0e56b3c111.jpg", "http://photo.interpressnews.ge/img/image1/5ff96384ddf214ef33706ffdb922b710.jpg");
    var imgnumber = 0;
    var imgleng = photos.length - 1;
    var img = document.getElementById("photo");
    var current = photos.indexOf(img.src);
    var nextindex;
    var back = document.getElementById("back");
    var forward = document.getElementById("forward");
    back.addEventListener('click', function(){toggleImage('back')});
    forward.addEventListener('click', function(){toggleImage('forward')});

    function toggleImage(direction) {
       if(direction == 'forward'){
         current = current != photos.length - 1 ? current + 1 : 0;
       } else {
         current = current != 0 ? current - 1 : photos.length - 1;
       }
       img.src = photos[current];
    }
```

Comment: thanks but now it get a stuck on 2 position. after one click it cannot show the next

Comment: You need to set current, not nextindex. Because otherwise it doesn't change the next time. I updated the code in the answer.